# Quadratic form - what method should be used?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism

A question - I have a polynomial

$$(q_1)^2+4\; q_1 \; q_2+2 \;(q_2)^2$$

I need to write this quadratic form as matrices and vectors, i.e row vector $[q1,q2]\cdot[\mathbf M ]$ all of this times another column vector of $q_1$,$q_2$.

What is the method that should be used here ? how can I know I do this via multiplication by 1 matrix and 2 or are there cases that I have no other way but to write this as a sum of 2 pieces as $v^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{M}v$

I tried a lot, tried taking my formulat and doing partial derivatives i.e 
$$M_{ij}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 P}{\mathrm{d}q_i\;\mathrm{d}q_j}$$

(where $P$ is the polynomial I have been given) this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess  this is more suitable for https://math.stackexchange.com/, but are you really just looking for an **M** giving you this polynomial?

If I get you right then it is just putting

$$ \left( \begin{matrix}
        x \\
        y 
        \end{matrix}\right)
\left( \begin{matrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d 
        \end{matrix}\right)
\left( \begin{matrix}
        x \\
        y 
        \end{matrix}\right)=x^2+4xy+2y^2
$$
Which has e.g. the solution $a=1$ and $b=c=d=2$. You can have other combinations of $b$ and $c$, but I guess symmetric is what you want.

By the way, if you change your try by derivatives to
$$
M_{ij}=\frac 1 2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2P}{\mathrm{d}q_i\;\mathrm{d}q_j}
$$
it should work, but only gives you the symmetric solutions

Comment: Actually that is what I want, (your most right vector should be a row vector no?), Is there any more elaborated explanation? (By the way this is my physics exercise so I put it here)

Comment: Right, so I guess the left would be a row vector....but actually after some years using this stuff you stop bothering...at least as physicist..maybe not as mathematician.

Comment: Elaborate explanation?...well, lets see: if there is a matrix then you can represent it in the most general form above. Multiplying it you get three equations $a=1$, $d=2$ and $b+c=4$. The result, hence, is not unique.That's pretty much it.

Comment: Although , the general topic of quadratic forms is by far more complicated.